# Matplotlib colormap not showing colors in 3D scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to Matplotlib and I'm trying to create a 3D scatter plot using `scatter3D`. I want to create 4 subplots with 4 different viewing angles with the "jet" colormap. The following is my code, however, I can't figure out why my cmap function is not working.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
ax = fig.add_subplot(444, projection='3d')

ax.set_xlabel('x', c='r', size=10)
ax.set_ylabel('y', c='r', size=10)
ax.set_zlabel('z', c='r', size=10)

x_data = df['x']
y_data = df['y']
z_data = df['z']

ax.scatter3D(df['x'],df['y'],df['z'],cmap='jet')

ax.view_init(0, 90)

# displaying the plot
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the data for colormapping using parameter `c`, otherwise, you'll get the warning:

```
UserWarning: No data for colormapping provided via 'c'. Parameters 'cmap' will be ignored
```

And then of course, use `add_subplot()` correctly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

data = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
x = np.sin(data)
y = np.cos(data)
z = x * y

# color varies according to the magnitude of Z
c = np.abs(z)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(221, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('x', c='r', size=10)
ax.set_ylabel('y', c='r', size=10)
ax.set_zlabel('z', c='r', size=10)
ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, c=c, cmap='jet')
ax.view_init(0, 0)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222, projection='3d')
ax2.set_xlabel('x', c='r', size=10)
ax2.set_ylabel('y', c='r', size=10)
ax2.set_zlabel('z', c='r', size=10)
ax2.scatter3D(x, y, z, c=c, cmap='jet')
ax2.view_init(45, 45)

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223, projection='3d')
ax3.set_xlabel('x', c='r', size=10)
ax3.set_ylabel('y', c='r', size=10)
ax3.set_zlabel('z', c='r', size=10)
ax3.scatter3D(x, y, z, c=c, cmap='jet')
ax3.view_init(0, 45)

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224, projection='3d')
ax4.set_xlabel('x', c='r', size=10)
ax4.set_ylabel('y', c='r', size=10)
ax4.set_zlabel('z', c='r', size=10)
ax4.scatter3D(x, y, z, c=c, cmap='jet')
ax4.view_init(0, -45)

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

> “There is a way out of every box, a solution to every puzzle; it’s just a matter of finding it.”–Captain Jean-Luc Picard

Answer (score 0):

If you want to color the points using a colormap then you need to tell matplotlib what to use to determine the colors by passing something to the `c`. In my example below, I pass the `z_data` to the colors, so the values are colored by their height (assuming z is up/down).

Since you didn't include any data, I used numpy to generate random numbers to plot. I've also 4 subplots rotated at different angles.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

N = 25
rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
x_data = rng.random(N)
y_data = rng.random(N)
z_data = rng.random(N)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2, subplot_kw={"projection":"3d"})
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):    
    ax.scatter3D(x_data, y_data, z_data, c=z_data, cmap="jet")
    
    ax.view_init(0, 45*i)
    ax.set_title(f"azim: {45*i}$^\circ$")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! This is close to what I want. However, Is there a way that I can make each subplot from a different angle?

Comment: @sundaynightlive I've updated my answer to include different views.